# Unity, how to get Camera angle Width

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, width

I'm making game that must set target number on all enemy on screen.
I FAIL TO FIND function like    IsInsideCameraView(gameObject)

Now I'm trying to scan area that camera looks.
For this, I need Camera angle width, angle hight.
[As described in this emage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwbLf.png) (My reputation is not enough to show image directly)

My question is similer to this question, [How to get angles value of perspective camera in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530357/how-to-get-angles-value-of-perspective-camera-in-three-js) but for Unity.

If you know 
HOW TO CALCULATE CAMERA WIDTH&HEIGHT (following screen size when unity starts)or
IS THERE GOOD FUNTIONS LIKE IsInsideCameraView(Camera, gameObject)

any answers will be welcomed.

Comment: There's no such thing as _"camera width"_.  There is _viewport width_

Answer (score 2):

[Untested. Javascript] You can use `renderer.isVisible` to determine if the object is within the camera frustum.

Answer (score 1):

> I FAIL TO FIND function like IsInsideCameraView(gameObject)

You can use:

```
object.Renderer.isVisible
```

...to check if the object is visible in **any camera**.

To test for a **specific** camera, use:

```
Vector3 screenPos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
```

Then check if `X` and `Y` coordinates are between (0,0) and `Screen.width`, `Screen.height`.

> HOW TO CALCULATE CAMERA WIDTH&HEIGHT

That's what `Camera.pixelWidth` and `Camera.pixelHeight` are for or you can use `Screen.width`, `Screen.height` for cameras that represent the entire screen.

Anyway, that's arguably a XY problem, refer to the beginning of my answer for direct solution.

### Tell me more

- [Is target in view frustum?](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-target-in-view-frustum.86136/)

Comment: wow seems like i miss usefull funtion. Thank you for your answer

Comment: information For other guys. accessing "Renderer" directly is outdated. need to use object.GetComponent<Renderer>().isVisible