# change axis of rotation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am taking help of sample code of [Transform tutorial](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/moving-visually-your-components-in-the-viewer-using-the-transformtool.html) for rotation and position change. I am facing couple of problems.

1. I want to perform rotation on door and window. Currently axis of rotation pass through center. How can I change to rotate a object from axis passing through its side.
2. For position change > when I change position lets say for a window in any direction, it moves but it is visible on wall. I want it hide when window collide with wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Here is a code snippet that illustrates how to rotate elements (fragments), for a more complete sample take a look at this article: [Rotate Components Control for the Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/rotate-component-control-for-the-viewer.html)

```
rotateFragments (model, fragIdsArray, axis, angle, center) {

  var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()

  quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle)

  fragIdsArray.forEach((fragId, idx) => {

    var fragProxy = this.viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(
      model, fragId)

    fragProxy.getAnimTransform()

    var position = new THREE.Vector3(
      fragProxy.position.x - center.x,
      fragProxy.position.y - center.y,
      fragProxy.position.z - center.z)

    position.applyQuaternion(quaternion)

    position.add(center)

    fragProxy.position = position

    fragProxy.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(
      quaternion, fragProxy.quaternion)

    if (idx === 0) {

      var euler = new THREE.Euler()

      euler.setFromQuaternion(
        fragProxy.quaternion, 0)

      this.emit('rotate', {
        dbIds: this.selection.dbIdArray,
        fragIds: fragIdsArray,
        rotation: euler,
        model
      })
    }

    fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()
  })
}
```

2/ When you transform the geometry, you are just moving triangles around, there is no built-in logic that will hide components because they overlap, you will need to implement that yourself. You should be able to find Three.js code that computes if two meshes intersect (triangle-triangle intersection algorithm) and run that against the component you are moving and all walls that are around. Here is something that can put you on tracks: [How to detect collision in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473755/how-to-detect-collision-in-three-js)

Hope that helps