# Camera Autorotate threejs

Tags: three.js

How can I make camera to autorotate when i hit any obstacle in threejs.  I referred the following link
http://threejs.live/#/webgl_raymarching_reflect
where the rendering restarts when it hits any obstacle.  I tried implementing in my project but that doesn't works. How can i implement that in my project?

My map.ts code is

```
private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  private camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  public scene: THREE.Scene;

  public fieldOfView: number = 10;
  public nearClippingPane: number = 1;
  public farClippingPane: number = 1000;

  public controls: THREE.OrbitControls;


  @ViewChild('canvas')
  private canvasRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    this.onModelLoadingCompleted = this.onModelLoadingCompleted.bind(this);

  }


  private get canvas(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
  }

  private createScene() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.load('assets/Buildings/Block.DAE', this.onModelLoadingCompleted);

  }

  private onModelLoadingCompleted(collada) {
     const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content:'Loading Please Wait...'
    });
    loading.present();

    var modelScene = collada.scene;
     modelScene.rotation.x = -0.01 * Math.PI;
    // modelScene.rotation.z = 0.03 * Math.PI;
    this.scene.add(modelScene);

    loading.dismiss();
    this.render();
  }

  private createCamera() {
    let aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    );

    // Set position and look at
    this.camera.position.x = 1;
    this.camera.position.y = 0.4;
    this.camera.position.z = 16;
  }

  private createLight(){
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
        this.scene.add( ambientLight );
        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
        directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1, 0 ).normalize();
        this.scene.add( directionalLight );

  }

  private getAspectRatio(): number {
    let height = this.canvas.clientHeight;
    if (height === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    this.canvas.style.width = "100%";
    this.canvas.style.height = "100%";
    return this.canvas.clientWidth / this.canvas.clientHeight;
  }

  private startRendering() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: this.canvas,
      antialias: true
    });
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);

    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
    this.renderer.autoClear = true;

    let component: MapComponent = this;

    (function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      component.render();
    }());
  }

  public render() {

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

  }

  public addControls() {
    this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera);
    this.controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
    this.controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
    this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);

  }

  /* EVENTS */

  public onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("onMouseDown");
    event.preventDefault();

    // Example of mesh selection/pick:
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / this.renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / this.renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, this.camera);

    var obj: THREE.Object3D[] = [];
    this.findAllObjects(obj, this.scene);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(obj);
    console.log("Scene has " + obj.length + " objects");
    console.log(intersects.length + " intersected objects found")
    intersects.forEach((i) => {
      console.log(i.object); // do what you want to do with object
    });

  }

  private findAllObjects(pred: THREE.Object3D[], parent: THREE.Object3D) {
    // NOTE: Better to keep separate array of selected objects
    if (parent.children.length > 0) {
      parent.children.forEach((i) => {
        pred.push(i);
        this.findAllObjects(pred, i);
      });
    }
  }

  public onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("onMouseUp");
  }


  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  public onResize(event: Event) {

    this.canvas.style.width = "100%";
    this.canvas.style.height = "100%";
    console.log("onResize: " + this.canvas.clientWidth + ", " + this.canvas.clientHeight);

    this.camera.aspect = this.getAspectRatio();
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);
    this.render();

  }


  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  public onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log("onKeyPress: " + event.key);
  }


  /* LIFECYCLE */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createScene();
    this.createCamera();
    this.createLight();
    this.startRendering();
    this.addControls();
  }
```

And map.html is

```
<canvas #canvas (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)" (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you clarify where you're stuck beyond "doesn't work"? Are you having trouble detecting collisions? Rotating the camera? Your code does not run in isolation, so we can't reproduce this easily. A JSFiddle or Codepen are often helpful.

Comment: I am stuck beyond in both detecting the collisions and rotating the camera.  I need my camera rotated as in the following link [http://blackshell.usebox.net/pub/canvas-raycasting/] How can this be implemented using threejs. Could you please help me with the component that is used in threejs to detect the collisions and to rotate the camera?? @Don McCurdy

Answer (score 0):

Use collision detection from three js utilities
Also use reference from this stack thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480717/16768028