# Three js RayCast between two object in scene

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I know how raycast object in scene when click on mouse, but now i need to know if two object in scene can raycast each other.

This is, i load a 3D Object in scene for example Two Rooms in OBJ object, then i add three mesh box in some points, for example two point on first room and one point on second room.

Then two points on first room can raycast each other(have direct vision), but two point for first room can't raycast point on second room.(they don't have vision through room wall).

I attached code used for load scene and points, any sugestion hwo to do?

```
//LOAD MAIN 3D OBJECT
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.setPath('./asset/3d/');
        objLoader.load("model01.obj", function(object){
            var mesh = object.children[0];
            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;

            mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

            var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( object )
            var ox = -(box.max.x + box.min.x) / 2;
            var oy = -(box.max.y + box.min.y) / 2;
            var oz = -(box.max.z + box.min.z) / 2;
            mesh.position.set(ox, oy, oz);

            _scene.add(mesh);

            render();

            setTimeout(render, 1000);

        }

//LOAD count_points inside scene
for(var i=0;i<cta_points;i++){
    var c_r = 2;
    var c_geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( c_r, c_r, c_r );
    var c_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color("rgb("+(40 +   30)+", 0, 0)"),opacity: 0.0,
                        transparent: true} );                       
    var c_mesh = new THREE.Mesh( c_geometry, c_material );
    var position = get_positions(i);
    c_mesh.position.copy(position);                                                 
    c_mesh.name="BOX";
    scene.add( c_mesh );    
}
```

Comment: `THREE.Raycaster()` has [`.set()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Raycaster.set) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly take a look at:

[How to detect collision in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473755/how-to-detect-collision-in-three-js)

Usually, to solve this problem, you would make a collision mask with a collision group.

The collision group is added per object, and is represented by a "bit" in a bitmask,

The wall could be in a separate collision group, like 4 (binary 100)

and the objects could be in another group, say 2 (binary 10)

Then you just need to check collisions of the object against the mask.

(check if the collision group matches against a bitmask (the masks above could be 10, 100,) to check for collisions).

So that way, you can call THREE.Raycaster().intersectObjects(args), where the arguments are the ones that pass the bitmask test ( mask == object.collision_group ).

That way, you won't need to include the wall for collision detection testing, since it is using a separate bitmask.